# Python __class__()

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, python-internals, object-model

In Python's documentation `__class__` is described as an attribute. In the object `type` (the metaclass), `__class__` appears to be a method.

If we do:

```
>>> class Foo:
        pass

>>> a = Foo()
>>> a.__class__ == type.__class__(a)
True
```

So, my questions are:

1. When we call `a.__class__`, are we really calling the method `type.__class__(a)`?
2. Is this the reason why `__class__` is not a member of the `__dict__` attribute of `a`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`__class__` is a [*data descriptor object*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). Many attributes on Python core objects are implemented as descriptors. You should see that as an implementation detail, nothing more.

`__class__` is a descriptor because Python needs to be able to validate new values you assign to it; there are certain limitations to assigning to `__class__` that need to be honoured, and making `__class__` a descriptor is the most efficient method of doing so.

Descriptor objects are automatically found and invoked on the type when you try to access the attribute on an object. `instance.__class__` will find and execute the `__class__` descriptor on the class (by searching through all classes in the inheritance graph), typically ending up with `object.__dict__['__class__'].__get__(instance, type(instance))` (where `object` is usually the first class on which the `__class__` attribute is found in the `type(instance).__mro__` sequence); This happens because Python will always use the type's `__getattribute__` method to find attributes, and that method knows how to handle descriptors found on the class and bases, as well as look at the `object.__dict__` attributes. So they don't live on the object `__dict__` itself, they live on the object type, by design.

Now, class objects are also *callable* objects. That's how you create an instance; for a given class `Foo`, you create an instance by calling it, so `Foo()`. `instance.__class__` is just a reference to the class object, just like `class_obj = Foo` would create a reference to a class. Calling the class object produces a new instance, whatever reference you used to get to it.

Finally, `type.__class__` is just a reference to `type()` itself:

```
>>> type.__class__ is type
True
>>> type.__class__
<class 'type'>
>>> type(type)
<class 'type'>
```

That's because `type` is its own type. The parent-child relationships of the Python type system must stop somewhere, and `type` is that point.

In your example, `a.__class__` is a reference to the `Foo` class. And `type.__class__` is the same object as `type`, so you essentially did this:

```
Foo == type(a)
```

which is indeed true, the type of `a` is `Foo`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now, you said:  `instance.__class__ ` will find and execute `type(instance).__dict__['__class__'].__get__(instance, type(instance))`  but if do: `type(instance).__dict__` there is not a    **__ class__** descriptor, which gets me to my first question, and assume that the descriptor **__ class__** exist only in the object **type** and is passed to all their instance objects (all classes). ?

Comment: @maxfraguas: sorry, I made things a little more confusing than I meant to. It's `object.__dict__['__class__']` that is the descriptor object; all classes inherit from that. The whole class hierarchy is searched for such attributes (so `next(t.__dict__['__class__'] for t in type(instance).__mro__ if '__class__' in t.__dict__).__get__(instance, type(instance))`.

Comment: Thanks @Matijn Pieters. After a little of playing around, I found `__class__` inside the **object**'s  `__dict__`.

Comment: Can this method be overriden?

Comment: @LexPodgorny: It's not a method, it's a data descriptor. Yes, you can create your own `__class__` data descriptor, e.g. by using a property with a setter.